# Firebase realtime database query on multiple attributes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, we have a contact management system where we store first name, last name and company name. i understand that firebase db cannot do those relational DB style queries using relational operators but is there a creative way to support that search can give results from either if the above 3 attributes.?

As an example:

```
{
"fName" : "abc",
"lName" : "pqr",
"cName" : "lmn"
},
{
"fName" : "pbc",
"lName" : "aqr",
"cName" : "tmn"
},
{
"fName" : "dbc",
"lName" : "tqr",
"cName" : "amn"
},
```

The query used currently is:

```
 this.db.list("/users/" + userKey + "/cards", 
ref => ref.orderByChild('fName').startAt('a').endAt('a' +"\uf8ff") )
```

With above query it will only return 1st record. What I need is to return all 3 as all 3 has at least one property beginning with 'a'

I think the other suggested tricks on other posts like creating another attribute combining values from other attributes wont work here. As they do a equalTo search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Realtime Database, you can only order and filter on a single child at a time.  So, what you're trying to do isn't possible given your current database structure *for a single query*.

What you can do instead is issue multiple queries, one for each field you want to check, and merge the results of each of those queries on the client.

Comment: yeah that was the only option i thought i have and was looking for any better option. no worries will go with that option